# What is the strategy to handle transactions in spring authorization server?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I have a bare-bones spring authorization server example up and running, and I have wired in jdbc-based user, client and authorization persistence.

So I am reading through the code, and around about [the bit of the authorization code provider that invalidates a code that has been used](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/cf801c36927172e5a19d29afd1e75be3b9571795/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/authentication/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java#L142) there is a race condition if the database runs with autocommit on - it is conceivable that another thread might get to read a valid token in between the if test checking if the authorization code is valid and persisting an invalid state. AFAICT the only way to avoid this kind of race condition is to properly demarcate transaction boundaries to ensure atomic operation.

I have set hikari.auto-commit: false in my application config and confirmed that my previously working tests started failing.

I tried to find something in the documentation about how you would like users to approach transactions, but I haven't found anything. Some guidance would be appreciated?

Comment: "it is conceivable that another thread might get to read a valid token" - Do you mean to say that two threads might see a valid token? This doesn't seem like a realistic scenario?

Comment: Imagine I have a compromised public client. An attacker promptly tries to use the token to hack me.

If my and the attackers request to exchange the authorization token arrive with very similar timing there is a race condition because the operations performed at the authorization server are not atomic - it operates in multiple transactions and threads.

I would like there to be some kind of ACID design in the service endpoints of the authorization server. Transaction and "select for update" would sort this.

Comment: If an attacker stole your authorization code and exchanged the authorization code for an access token, then you have a much more serious problem than ensuring database consistency. How would transactions mitigate that attack?

Comment: Transactions would mitigate the attack because there would be no dual use of a single authorization code, which I think is an assumption in oauth.

With transactions in place, the second use of the authorization code would be guaranteed to cause any existing authorization entry to be deleted, and the dual use would be logged, closing any avenue for exploitation.

(Also, not having transactions in place might lead the database to end up half-updated during a crash, which might be hard to recover from - or to lead to security issues.)